# Spread one reducer result in combineReducers in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am combining 2 reducers say `one: {a, b, c}, two: {x, y, z}` into 1, but I want `one` to be spread in the result. something like this:

```
{
  a,
  b,
  c,
  two : {x, y, z}
}
```

I tried this:

```
combineReduceres({...one, two})
```

but this results in:

```
{ two : {x, y, z}}
```

does someone have any solution to this..

Comment: Man, have u found a way?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's not possible to do so. At least with the provided API.

As stated in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers):

> The state produced by `combineReducers()` namespaces the states of each reducer under their keys as passed to `combineReducers()`.

But you can achieve this functionality by writing a custom combiner.

Here is a working sandbox:

[image: Edit Stackoverflow#53457875]

**Note:** This code is a simplified version of the one available in the redux code base. Some validation parts were excluded to make the code simpler. You can find the complete `combineReducers` code [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js).

Comment: this won't work, variable `previousStateForKey` will stay undefined for spreaded key if  an action is triggered.

Comment: @BharatSoni Yes, you're right. I didn't test dispatching actions. The code is updated now. My apologies.

Comment: Ur example when u use it in createStore. Could u suggest the implementation inside combineReducers

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this way. I used the custom reducer as well

```
const combineReducersWithSpread = ( reducers, ...reducerNamesForSpread ) => {
  const reducerKeys = Object.keys( reducers )
  if ( !reducerKeys.length ) {
    return (
      'Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed ' +
      'to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.'
    )
  }
  return ( state = {}, action ) => reducerKeys.reduce(
    ( obj, key ) => {
      obj[ key ] = reducers[ key ]( state[ key ], action )
      const isReducerForSpread = reducerNamesForSpread.includes( key )
      return isReducerForSpread ? { ...obj[ key ] } : obj
    },
    {},
  )
}
```

This is an example of how to call this function

```
const yourReducer = combineReducersWithSpread(
  {
    nameReducer
  },
  'nameReducer', // here you put all keys of reducers separated by commas for the spread
)
```